# How do you keep Visual Studio tabs sorted

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is there a built in way, or a free add-in, that can keep the tab bar of open files sorted in alphabetical order? Once sorted, how can I get CTRL-PageUP/DOWN (or other shortcut) to jump left/right instead of most/least recently viewed file.

Thanks,
Kurt

Answer (score 12):

In VS 2017, using the Productivity Power Tools extension you can navigate to:

TOOLS > Options > Productivity Power Tools > Custom Document Well

Here you'll see a 'Sorting' section, where you can select 'Alphabetically'.

With the new settings applied the CTRL + PAGE DOWN (or in my case, CTRL + ALT + PAGE DOWN) will just flip between next/previous windows.

--

In VS 2019, they [aren't able to port the Custom Document Well extension](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/465490/update-support-for-custom-document-well-to-visual.html) so you'll have to [vote for this feature to be added to Visual Studio](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/477172/tab-sorting-in-document-well.html) instead.

--

I don't have VS 2008, so I'm not sure if the path to get to those setting is exactly the same. If you are unable to find it, you should be able to install Productivity Power Tools from the Extensions and Updates module (also located under TOOLS).

Hope that helps!

Comment: What I was looking for, but it would have been nice to mention Productivity Power Tools is an extension.

Comment: Sorry about that, I think in 2017 it's installed by default (Or maybe I forgot I installed it). I've edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: To add an update - according to your developercommunity link, this was completed and added to VS 2019 16.5 preview 2. You can go to Tools > Options > Environment > Tabs and Windows

Answer (score 2):

It is not perfect but the downward-pointing triangle just to the left of the **X** that closes the current editor tab does display all currently opened files in alphabetical order.

Comment: Old question, but in VS2017 with Productivity Power Tools this gets you to the right Preferences page where you can manage tab sorting.  Mine were sorting alphabetically, and I wanted to stop it.  Your answer got me there, so thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I use ReSharper's "[Go To...](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#Go_to_Symbol)":

[image: Go To File]
<sub>(source: [jetbrains.com](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/screenshots/40/navigation_gotofile.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Use the VS Studio extension "Sort Tabs/Open Editors by name" by omagerio.

Close all your tabs.

Go to this extension settings and uncheck "Sort by full path"

Answer (score 0):

I always switch VS from Tabs to MDI. With tabs on, after working for a while there are so many documents the tab bar gets meaningless.

I use Resharper and Ctrl-T with CamelCase(CC) to get to my classes, or a simple old-fashioned Ctrl-Tab.